# From list create multiple list with restrictions in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm currently working on a task in python 2.6.9 where I need to get all possible options from a list. I started with a couple of for-loops but I'm having trouble to even understand how to tackle this problem.

So this is the list I've got:

> [[spl_1, spl_2], [spl_2, spl_3], [spl_2, spl_4], [spl_3, spl_5], [spl_4, spl_6]]

From this list I want to create four other lists.

List 1:

> [[spl_1, spl_2], [spl_2, spl_3], [spl_3, spl_5]]

List 2:

> [[spl_1, spl_2], [spl_2, spl_4], [spl_4, spl_6]]

List 3:

> [[spl_5, spl_3], [spl_3, spl_2], [spl_2, spl_1]]

List 4:

> [[spl_6, spl_4], [spl_4, spl_2], [spl_2, spl_1]]

Comment: This looks like you want to do some combination https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/permutation-and-combination-in-python/#highlighter_373596

Comment: Please explain the mechanism by which you combine the result lists... Is it all possible combinations of 3 lists out of the original set? Or chains of 3 elements that have at an element in common.. PS: Python 2.7 is out of date (at least 5 years).. please do not contribute to the reasons why it is still around learn to use python 3.x instead.

Comment: The second string in the first list is the same as the first string in the second list and the second string in the second list is the same as the first string in the third list and so on.

The reason for using python 2.7 is compatibility with the current system (really old)